# Like Spring boot, can I switch to a different http server in vertx?

Tags: vert.x

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html

Spring boot allows changing the web server, other than the embedded Tomcat server. Does Vertx provide similar capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Vert.x* is implemented over [netty](/questions/tagged/netty) (*A lightweight event-driven network application framework*).

Under the hood, starting a *Vert.x* `HttpServer` [bootstraps a *Netty* server by default](https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/http/impl/HttpServerImpl.java#L249): meaning ***you cannot switch to another implementation***.

Answer (score 0):

While it should be possible to use Vertx with any web server, Vertx comes with a HttpServer in the [Vert.x-Web package](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_re_cap_on_vert_x_core_http_servers) that can deliver static files and has routing options, role and security features and many more.
All of these are optional, yet pretty easy to use/implement if you follow the documentation. Also see all the other [available modules](https://vertx.io/docs/).

If you use the Vertx webserver module you don't need a container like Tomcat, you can deploy a fat-jar and start that like any java application.

Answer (score 0):

You could as well use nginx as a reverse proxy in front of vertx. This setup gives you more flexibility and you can use the full power of nginx for serving static files, your ssl configuration, gziping etc.